# Ford-Fulkerson max flow algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm, graph, ford-fulkerson

I am reading Ford-Fulkerson maxflow algorithm in book Algorithms written by Robert Sedgewick. Here author mentioned as below

> The number of augmenting paths needed in the shortest-augmenting-path
>   implementation of the Ford-Fulkerson maxflow algorithm for a flow
>   network with V vertices and E edges is at most EV /2.
>
> Proof sketch: Every augmenting path has a critical edge—an edge that
>   is deleted from the residual network because it corresponds either to
>   a forward edge that becomes filled to capacity or a backward edge that
>   is emptied. Each time an edge is a critical edge, the length of the
>   augmenting path through it must increase by 2. Since an augmenting
>   path is of length at most V each edge can be on at most V/2 augmenting
>   paths, and the total number of augmenting paths is at most EV/2.

My questions on above text are

1. How we got by saying if augumenting path length is atmost V, each edge can be in atmost V/2 augumenting paths?

Request to explain above with simple example if possible.

Comment: Is this more appropriate for the Computer Science SE?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to prove the previous statement

> Each time an edge is a critical edge, the length of the augmenting path through it must increase by 2.

A path length is at most V because it doesn't make sense to go through a vertex twice(remove all the edges between the two occurrences of a vertex x on such a path and you will still have a good path, with capacity at least that of the original path).

So, if the path length is at most V and every time an edge is critical the length of the path increases by 2, then an edge can be critical at most V/2 times.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Sorry but I didn't get still. What do you mean by statement "remove all the edges between the two occurrences of a vertex x on such a path ". ?

Comment: If you have a path `source, a,B,c,d,e,f,g,B, sink` then you can get another path between source and sink by removing the intermediate stepst between the `B`'s to get `source, a, B, sink`. the new path always reaches the same destination and it's capacity is at least as big as the original longer path. Basically it's saying it doesn't make sense to go through a vertex twice.